# MediaWiki Extension to register new user

Tags: mediawiki

I made `OnBeforeinitialize` hook. I need place there code which register new user if user doesn't exists in database.

Which MediaWiki class and functions should be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if I don't know, what you really want to do, where the data for the user should came from, and why you want to do this in the `BeforeInitialize` hook (so, in fact, any useful information to really know and understand what you want to achieve is missing, therefore, you'll get an answer to your concrete question without any guarantee, that it works like you expected in your use case). However, to create a new user, you can use the [`createNew`](https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/master/php/classUser.html#a7765442b495de3431cad60966d45e745) function of the `User` class. You should check, if the user is already present in the database.

EDIT:
An usage example:

```
$user = User::createNew( 'Testuser', [ 'email' => 'email_from@external_source.com' ] );
```

Comment: Please can you show code examples how to correctly use function User::createNew() ?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to create users, chances are you are doing something wrong. Users should be created on login/signup (use a `PrimaryAuthenticationProvider` to tell the system to create them), or when they are authenticated based on request data (use a `SessionProvider`). There is also `User::newSystemUser` but it's only meant for scripts.